# Как рекурсивно заменить value 1 массива value другого?

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть 2 массива - они одинаковые по структуре. на подобии

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
(
[0] => 123
[1] => 412412
[2] => 21424124
)
)
```

и есть 2 массив

```
Array(
[32] => Array
(
[7] => 4124124
[8] => 124124
[9] => 124124
)
```

Это только маленький кусок массива, на самом деле там около 50 значений в 1 и в 2 массиве тоже.
По дереву они полностью идентичные - вся разница заключается в том что у них разные ключи.
Как можно заменить value1ого массива (value2)м втого массива при этом не трогая ключи ? я я пробовал 
array_merge и array_merge_recursive так же replace тоже не помогло, посоветуйте кто сталкивался с таким есть ли какое-то простое решение для такой задачи ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо что типо такого алгоритма

```
$array1; // исходный массивы
$array2; // массив донор

foreach($array1 as $_key => $_arr) {
  $_arr2 = current($array2);
  next($array2);
  foreach($_arr as $_subarraykey => $_subarrayval) {
    $_subarray2val = current($_arr2);
    next($_arr2);
    $array1[$_key][$_subarraykey] = $_subarray2val;
  }
}
```

т.е. алгоритм прост он как бы делает паралельный `foreach` двух массивов с помощью `next` передвигая внутрений указатель вперёд, и получаем текущее значение с помощью `current`.

пример http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/206a2090a42a9cc3f862a1318606f833a12b34c5

Comment: спасибо помогло )